# Find all occurances of 'Php' on page ignoring case BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Im looking to find all the occurances of `Php` on a page (ignoring case) with `BeautifulSoup` in `Python3`

`Php` (regardless of case) could occur anywhere on the page, so I am trying to basically just find the `string` representation, and not within a specific div, or class.

I currently have:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    school_urls = ['somesite1.com','somesite2.com']
    posting_keywords = ['PHP', 'Php', 'php']

    for school in school_urls:
```

`school` contains *html markup* from `request`ing a url with words like `php` in it.

How does this look to you? Is there a way to do this in Beautiful soup to find all variations of `php` ignoring the case instead of having to loop through `posting_keywords`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running this?  Does it work?  Does it fail? What's your question?

Comment: I did test it, the problem is, if 'Php' is in say a link, it finds it. I want it only if its text e.g. `<a href="somesitelink.com">Php Rocks</a>`, not a link e.g. `a href="somesite.com/php-rocks">some text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Does posting_keywords.lower() work for you.

Comment: That would look for only `php`. I want to find `Php` or `PHP` in html output if it exists too

Comment: Could this `lower` method be applied to `res` above ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, bs4
text = '''"""
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story php</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story PHP</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">php</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Php</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">php Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'php', re.IGNORECASE))
```

out:

```
["The Dormouse's story php",
 "The Dormouse's story PHP",
 'php',
 'Php',
 'php Tillie']
```

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)